# Flask not displaying http address when I run it

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to run the Hello World using Flask framework :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello() -> str:
    return 'Hell world from Flask!'
app.run()
```

Then I go to my cmd and I run my script according to the documentation:

```sh
set FLASK_APP = flaskhello.py
python -m flask run
```

And what I get is a grey window with a click me header and when I click it i get the X and Y but I don't get the http address on my cmd to run it on browser. What should I do to correct this ?

I've already installed flask correctly as it seems, but I'm not sure.

edit. I also tried creating a new venv and the same happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing old and new documentation. You can lose the last line in flaskhello.py (`app.run()`). Then, don't pass the `flask run` command to python, but run it directly in the CMD. So not `python -m flask run`, but `flask run`.

Comment: The same thing happens there's no console for the http address

Comment: I just removed every old python file from my directory and now it seems to be working fine I don't know what was the issue exactly but some file was interfering with flask. Thanks both of you

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and it is serving a page with `Hell world from Flask!`, are you sure your flask servers starts, do you see the following in the console:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2019 13:35:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Starting with Flask 0.11 there are multiple built-in ways to run a development server. The best one is the flask command line utility (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/server/)

```
export FLASK_APP= flaskhello.py
flask run
```

[image]

Comment: No I don't see the console that's exactly my problem, maybe it's an installation problem?